# Does the initialization vector (IV) for AES encryption in Java contain the password?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

After reading different threads I've put together the following test code to encrypt and decrypt a string. In the real application the encrypted string will be stored in a file and decrypted after restarting the application and reading the file. Therefore I've to store the initialization vector (IV), too. In test code this is simulated by holding the IV in a member variable `initializer`. After all, application and test code work fine.

But I wonder, whether the password becomes somehow part of the IV: password goes into `keySpec`, `keySpec` is used to generate the `secretKey`, `secretKey` becomes part of `secretKeySpec` which is used to initialize `cipher`, the IV is retrieved from the parameter spec of the parameters of `cipher` ...

... so the password is potentially part of the IV, isn't it? And I don't want to store the password along with the encrypted text, of course.

```
@Test
public void test06() throws Exception {
    char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
    String s = "an unencryted string to be encrypted and decrypted";
    byte[] sEncrypted = encrypt(password, s);
    String sEncryptedDecrypted = decrypt(password, sEncrypted);
    Assert.assertEquals(s, sEncryptedDecrypted);
}

private static final byte[] KEY_SALT = { (byte) 0xc7, (byte) 0x73, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0x8c, (byte) 0x7e,
        (byte) 0xc8, (byte) 0xee, (byte) 0x99 };
private static final int KEY_ITERATION_COUNT = 1024;
private static final String CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 128;
private static final String SECRET_KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final String CHARSET_NAME = "UTF-8";
private byte[] initializer;

public byte[] encrypt(final char[] password, final String s) throws Exception {
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password, KEY_SALT, KEY_ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SECRET_KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    initializer = cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    return cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
}

public String decrypt(final char[] password, final byte[] sEncrypted) throws Exception {
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password, KEY_SALT, KEY_ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
    SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SECRET_KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
    SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(initializer));
    final byte[] sByteArray = cipher.doFinal(sEncrypted);
    return new String(sByteArray, CHARSET_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the IV is not generated based on the password. The IV is randomly generated, and used to ensure that you don't get the same ciphertext if you encrypt the same plaintext twice with the same key.

Comment: There is no telling what a cryptographic provider might do, but it would be quite strange if the key would be used to generate the IV. At least the OpenJDK SunJCE provider uses pure randomness ([link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/crypto/provider/CipherCore.java#461)).

Comment: Thanks for your very fast replies. Being still curious I debugged into the code with OpenJDK 7 and found `random.nextBytes(ivBytes)` in `CipherCore.init(opmode, key, params, random)` which in the end generates the IV.

Comment: Yes, Artjom B. added a link to this very class, I had overlooked it.